# Where can I download TradingView's technical charting library?

Tags: download, tradingview-api

I am trying to create a new web project and want to use [Technical Analysis Charts](https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/?feature=technical-analysis-charts) library, but when I want to download it, it asks for giving a public website domain that I don't have! It's an educational project and I don't have a company or created web site for it.
Is there anywhere that I can download the library?

Comment: Did you access the library?

Answer (score 3):

It says, it's for a public project in its FAQ.

---

## Can I get charting library for personal use?

At this time, we do not provide Technical Analysis Charts for personal use, hobbies, studies, or testing. The FREE Technical Analysis Charts license can be provided only to companies and/or individuals for use in public web projects and/or applications.